# How to install binary portably

Tags: binary, installation, posix

Is there a portable way to install binaries? For example is it guaranteed by POSIX that there is always /usr/local/bin (and included in the search path). Or is distribution alway platform dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX doesn't guarantee that, but something else might, depending on the OS. In the case of Linux that would be the [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base).

In my experience, you cannot count on `/usr/local/*` being universally present. They will not be present on fresh clean installs of some flavours of UNIX. That should be rare though. It is a de facto standard location where third-party software can be placed, and install scripts should not have any qualms about creating `/usr/local` itself as well as its well-known subdirectories like `bin` and `lib` if they don't exist and installing things there.

Of course, good software will use that as a default but give the user a choice in case they want to change it.

I'm not sure whether you meant your question to be about installation more generally or just the pathnames & locations? Like what command to use to in a Makefile recipe to install things (usually `install`)?

Comment: Sorry about being not clear enough. What i meant is, if there is a way to write a script or makefile, that will install a binary on any POSIX platform in a way that the binary can be executed by the system shell without specifying the exact path.

Comment: np. Like I said, you can't guarantee anything, but `/usr/local/bin` is a pretty safe bet. It's going to be in the default `$PATH` of almost everything out there already, and in the esoteric cases where it's not, the sysadmin can add it.